# 1D Motion under Gravity

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, projectile, kinematics

I have attempted this question in so many different ways but I am getting nowhere. Could someone point me in the correct direction so I can work it out myself?

Here is the question:

> *An object $K$ is shot upwards with a velocity $v_i$, after $t$ seconds it is 50 metres high and time $2t$ seconds it is 80 metres high.  Solve for $v_i$ and $t$.*

I have tried breaking it into two parts but I always hit a wall.

Comment: Can you show how far you got?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes a good picture is worth a hundred words.
[image]

**If you can take it from here, don't read the rest of the answer.**

So the system of equations will be:

> $$\left( v_i - \frac{g\tau}{2}\right)\tau=50 \\ \left( v_i - \frac{3g\tau}{2}\right)\tau=30$$

Subtracting them we get:

> $$g\tau^2=20$$

Assuming $g \approx 10$, we will have:

> $$\Rightarrow \tau = \sqrt {2} \\ v_i = \frac{60}{\sqrt 2}$$

Comment: Thank you sir, that is a perfect explanation.  Once I saw the diagram it all became clear

Comment: A small question, would you mind telling me how you got 3gt in equation 2.

Comment: Area of a [trapezoid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trapezoid) is $\frac{a+b}{2}h$.